# Auto-populate one table from another table if a criteria is met

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have two tables: Information and List.

The Information table has two columns: Name and Gender.

The List table also has two columns: Male and Female.

I'm trying to auto-populate the List table with the names of the people who are either male or female, by using formulas.

I tried to use `INDEX()` and `MATCH()`

```
=INDEX(A:A, MATCH(D1, B:B, 0),1)
```

but it only returns the first name with the corresponding gender.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the matched data skips rows, you cannot use a simple index/match formula to extract the names (without using helper columns, that is).

The simplest solution requires the use of an array formula:

[image: Worksheet Screenshot]

Array enter (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>) the following formula in `D2` and copy-paste/fill-down/fill-right into the rest of the table columns `D` and `E` (don't forget to remove the `{` and `}`):

```dart
{=IFERROR(INDEX($A:$A,SMALL(IF($B$2:$B$7=D$1,ROW($B$2:$B$7),FALSE),ROW()-1)),"")}
```

The formula works by initially constructing an array that contains the row index if the gender matches, or `FALSE` otherwise: `IF($B$2:$B$7=D$1,ROW($B$2:$B$7),FALSE)`.

Then the `SMALL()` function is used to extract the next smallest index corresponding to the data row of the List table: `SMALL({…},ROW()-1)`. The reason this works is that the `SMALL()` function ignores boolean values.

Note that, if entering the formula in any row other than row `2`, or if after entering the formula rows are inserted/deleted above the first List table data row, the `ROW()-1` part needs to be adjusted so that the result is 1 for the first data row.

Finally, this index is used to extract the appropriate name: `INDEX($A:$A,<next smallest index>)`.

The `IFERROR()` is just there to hide the `#NUM!` errors that occur when the `SMALL()` function runs out of valid indexes to return.

---

A more robust, but more complicated, version of the formula that automatically adjusts for the number of data rows in the Information table, and won't break if rows are inserted/deleted above the first data row of the List table, follows:

```dart
{=IFERROR(INDEX($A:$A,SMALL(IF($B$1:INDEX($B:$B,COUNTA($B:$B))=D$1,ROW($B$1:INDEX($B:$B,COUNTA($B:$B))),FALSE),ROW()-ROW($B$2)+1)),"")}
```